# C++ vector, list or array for fixed size and predefined type data

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, list, vector

I'm trying to select the appropriate data type for a new project to fit the following requirements:

- Highly! time critical (for inputting the data)
- No random insert or any operation on data in container (read only and insert sequentially)
- The size will be fixed on compile time (so no need for dynamic alloc)
- The data will be deleted sequencially after some defined time period (by a thread or sevice) and the empty space must be available for the new coming data again.

ex. let's say 1,2,3,4,5,6 inserted into the container. After some time 6 will be deleted and 7 will be inserted so the list would be 7,1,2,3,4,5 and then 5 will deleted etc... but the size must be same.

I was wondering which data structure will be the most efficient and suitable one for my situtation from performance and memory point of view.

Thanks...

edit: by the way its a little bit different froö the basic FIFO logic because lets say we create 10 elements (size) data container but inserted only 3 elements even it has not reach the end of the container(limit of the size), if the specified time passed it would be deleted.

By the way i was thinking about to use boost:array but a little bit confused about std:vector and std:deque. Is there any specific advantage in this situtaion?

Comment: For fast the inserts and deletes on the ends, use a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) and limit the size, or just use an array.

Comment: What do you think and what have you tried?

Comment: i haven't try anything up to now, i'm just trying to decide the data structure first because its the heart of the project, the functionality is not that difficult. I was thinking about to use boost:array but wondered anybody has better solution or similar experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a **cyclic buffer** build on fixed-size array, this is very simple and the fastest data structure.

You can write your own **cyclic buffer class** or try to use boost implementation of cyclic buffer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Comment: hm, cicular buffer would be good solution, and as far as i see it has the same iteration functionality with boost:array or std:vector. But only the difference in my problem is; no new data will replace the old one. The data will be deleted even if the prespecified time has passed, in other saying when the data has time outted otherwise the data will be available for the client applications. So do i need a circular structure indeed?

Comment: Let's take your example: 1,2,3,4,5,6 you delete 6 and insert 7 at the beginning - no new data is replacing old data, but the first element is different now, to change first element in constant time standard array is not enough

Comment: So the iterator "begin" changes if we delete the first entered (oldest) (in our ex its 6 (and we are not replacing 6 by the way we have still lets say 10 more empty space)) in both containers (standart array & circular buffer) right? I mean so if thats the case why standart array is not enough and what is the advantage of circular buffer anyway, i mean what is the difference? I'm sorry if my question sounds silly, i'm just trying to figure out if the circular buffer has an advantage for this situation. thanks for the help...

Comment: show me how would you place those items in the array, is it?
[<empty>, <empty>, <empty>, <empty>, ..., 1,2,3,4,5,6]
then
[<empty>, <empty>, <empty>, <empty>, ..., 7, 1,2,3,4,5, <empty>]

Comment: Yes, most probably the way that you wrote. But the thing is we must have the possiblity to use the last empty place (the place of 6 after deletion) with out losing the insertion order. Is it possible in circular buffer? Once again the insertion sequence is very important in our case.

Comment: It's possible in circular buffer, it's not possible in array. Circular buffer example
to_insert: 0, first:0 [<empty>, ...]; insert 1, insert 2 [1,2, <empty>, ...] to_insert:2, first:0;  remove 1 [<empty>, 2, <empty>, ...] to_insert:2, first:1; and so on, if to_insert reaches max size, it goes to the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/), probably backed up by some optimized fixed-size container with FIFO support.

Answer (score 0):

We all know from our data structures and algorithm classes that where inserts and deletes are likely we should use a linked list of some sort.  It might be that what we know is wrong though.

Modern memory is blisteringly fast copying huge chunks of data around (so you shouldn't worry as much as you think about copying data around) and uses caching for linear searches (which a linked list structure will effectively defeat).  These two factors combined may well mean you should use a good old vector or boost::array.

But don't take my word for it, [here's  Bjarn Stroustrup  explaining it all.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo%E2%80%8E)

Answer (score 0):

You need std::queue backed by std::vector with some fixed capacity:

```
std::vector<YourType> underlying_storage(capacity);
std::queue<YourType, std::vector<YourType>> queue(std::move(underlying_storage));

// Now your queue is backed up by vector with predefined capacity
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution for this is a statically-allocated array where you handle the queue yourself using head/tail/count; for example

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS 10

// Use statically-allocated memory
unsigned char raw_buf[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(X)];
X * const buf = (X *)&raw_buf[0];
int head, tail, count;

// Returns the address for a new element on the queue
inline void *add_element_address() {
    void *p = &buf[head];
    if (++head == MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS) head = 0;
    count++;
    return p;
}

// Removes oldest element from the queue
inline void remove_element() {
    buf[tail].~X();
    if (++tail == MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS) tail = 0;
    count--;
}

// Get the n-th element from the queue where 0 is the
// last added element and count-1 is the oldest one.
X& element(int index) {
    index = head - index - 1;
    if (index < 0) index += MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS;
    return buf[index];
}

void add_element(... constructor arguments ...) {
    new (add_element_address()) X(... constructor arguments ...);
}
```

With this approach the buffer will be at a fixed address in memory (thus also freeing a register) and no copy of any kind is needed on the objects (they're constructed directly in place using placement new). Adding, removing and indexed access operations are all `O(1)`.